# python multiprocessing return value time

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a simple function which reads a HDF5 files and returns a pandas dataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocess as mp

def read_file(filename):
   store = pd.HDFStore(filename, 'r')
   df = store['df']
   return df


filename = ['20150320', '20150323','20150302']

T = Timer()
T.start()
pool = mp.Pool(processes=3)
results=pool.map(getG1X1Day, dates)
T.done('done')
```

The output I have is

```
load 20150323...: 8.363
load 20150320...: 8.898
load 20150302...: 11.316
done: 39.110
```

The run time is longer than reading each file separately. Why will this happen and how to solve this? Would like to read hundreds of file and read X of them in parallel.

Thanks!

Comment: If you really want to speed things up with multiprocessing, you should try to do the *actual work* on the data in the `Pool`, without shuffling lots of data from child to parent process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the cost of communication with the child process. The child pickles the dataframe, sends it to the parent and then the parent unpickles the dataframe. This could easily be more expensive than just reading the dataframe in the parent.

Since a fair amount of the work is being done without holding the GIL, you may find a thread pool is faster. Substitute `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` for pool and see what happens.

Also, if you can delegate the dataframe processing to the child, you'll benefit from multiprocessing again.